# Vuetify - mutliple select, but instead of chips, display selected value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to select multiple items in my Vuetify v-select component, but instead of showing them (in a line or using chips) I would like the text to just say 'selected'. New to Vue so not really sure where to start, but here's my code for the v-select component:

```html
<v-select
    v-else-if="isMobile"
    class="customizable-dropdown"
    :items="getSortedItems"
    :label="$t('dropdown.label.all')"
    multiple
    rounded
    single-line
    @change="onChange"
>    
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the selection slot to customize the display of the selected item...

```
<template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
  <span class="pr-3">{{ item }}</span>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/qyNkWIdA2w)